# import org.apache.http components cannot be resolved

Tags: android-studio, androidhttpclient

I have a problem with my org.apache.http components. Im creating a registration page and importing the ff:

```
  import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
  import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
  import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
  import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
  import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
  import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
  import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
  import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
  import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
```

Ive also change my build.gradle into this

```
 android {

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

and this :
           dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

```
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

but im still getting the error. I've learned that HttpClient is not supported anymore in API23. is there anyway to do to be able to create my registration. Please help me :) Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

using build tools 19.1.0 gets me working without issues however the error will be reported when you open the file, but you should be able to build your project

Comment: if i downgrade my buildtoolsversion from 23 to 19, will it affect my designs ?

Comment: nope ..design is by the api level not build version

Comment: Ive already change my buildtoolsversion into 19.1.0 but im still getting the error .

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help someone as it did with me.
Latest Solution to this problem is to add:

```
implementation 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
```

in your gradle dependencies:

```
build.gradle > dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
}
```

Clean Project, Rebuild, All Done.